# Casting a List<T> (where T : IBar) to ICollection<IBar> fails

Tags: c#, list, interface, casting, icollection

I have `class`**`T`**, implementing `interface`**`IBar`**.

I have a variable `list` of type `List<T>`.

Two questions for enhancing my understanding of the language:

- Why doesn't this work?

  `var foo = (ICollection <IBar>)list; // fails!`
- How to work around it (if possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work?: `var foo = (ICollection <IBar>)list;`

Let's say `T = Foo` and there's a second class `Foo2 : IBar`.

Then you could continue like this:

```
var foolist = (ICollection <IBar>)list;
foolist.Add(new Foo2());  // compiles, since Foo2 also implements IBar
```

Wham! You have a type violation at runtime, since you tried to add a `Foo2` to a `List<Foo>`.

To avoid this, `ICollection<Foo>` is *not* a subtype of `ICollection<IBar>`, even though `Foo` is a subtype of `IBar`. The theory behind this is [co- and contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).